# Pandas regression calculating 'nan' for some standard errors?

Tags: pandas

I'm running a multivariate regression using pandas on a fairly large dataset with ~40 independent variables. However, for some of these variables, pandas can calculate a coefficient but not the standard error (and thus not the t-stat, p-value, etc.). Here's a part of the regression output:

```
...
 var1      0.0000     0.0001       0.46     0.6488    -0.0002     0.0002
 var2     25.8603        nan        nan        nan        nan        nan
 var3      9.5578        nan        nan        nan        nan        nan
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 var4     -4.7974        nan        nan        nan        nan        nan
 var5      2.9619        nan        nan        nan        nan        nan
 var6      1.9343        nan        nan        nan        nan        nan
 var7    -24.8932        nan        nan        nan        nan        nan
 var8      4.7703        nan        nan        nan        nan        nan
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 var9    -16.0344        nan        nan        nan        nan        nan
 var10     5.8313        nan        nan        nan        nan        nan
 var11    -3.1322        nan        nan        nan        nan        nan
 var12     5.5747     1.4304       3.90     0.0001     2.7711     8.3784
 var13     4.0470     1.8455       2.19     0.0284     0.4299     7.6641
...
```

Note that all the vars with nan are binary variables, but of the variables where there are standard errors, some are binary and others are normal continuous variables.

Has anybody experienced this before?

Comment: Could you post a subset of the source data that shows the same behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Think I found the answer: those binary variables that had the 'nan' problem led to multicollinearity (every data point was 1 for exactly one of the dummy variables in that set). Removing one of these dummy variables fixed the problem! Didn't think pandas would still try to calculate things with this data but it does!